# jupyter notebook with multiple environments

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda, environment

I started using jupyter notebook and was confronted with following problem:
I wanted to run the code in my own conda-environment (not in the base conda-environment).
I found the solution for my problem: I installed the package nb_conda into my environment. Now, it works just fine. However, if I start jupyter notebook, I can choose from 3 different kernels (see also attached picture):

1. Python 3
2. Python [conda env: cenv1]
3. Python [conda env: root]

Number 2 is clear. This is my own environment. What is the difference between number 1 and 3?

[image]

Comment: You could try answering this yourself by switching between them and running `import sys; print(sys.executable)`. Also, while `nb_conda` is a fine package, it is not necessary to use envs as kernels. The package most people actually want is `nb_conda_kernels`.

Comment: `print(sys.executable)` was a good hint